# Django edit in place package installation

Tags: django

I am trying to utilize the package for editing html content in place and saving it into my database.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-inplaceedit
```

I've never used Django before until this past week and am wondering how I can install this to be able to use it in my project. I've only been used to using pip install commands and can't seem to use that for this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you answer your own question successfully?  I was going to augment to include a bit about adding apps to django but if you figured out what you needed, will skip

Comment: I got the question answered, thanks! Maybe for helping anyone else if they may have a similar question.

Comment: Have you installed pip already? Which OS do you use?